# How to not display the LibreOffice file picker / loader when closing any LibreOffice application?

Tags: linux-mint, debugging, libreoffice, bugs

Until today, when I closed any LibreOffice application (e.g. Writer, Calc, Draw, Impress, etc.) in Linux Mint, the expected happened: LibreOffice would close.

Now, suddenly, when I close any LibreOffice application, the LibreOffice file picker (AKA the LibreOffice loader/launcher) is displayed.

LibreOffice did not have any recent updates.

What caused this, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After much time spent determining the cause of the issue, I figured out it is a bizarre side-effect (or bug?) caused by the [`Cinnamon Maximus` Linux Mint extension](https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/extensions/view/73).

Although the extension should have no effect on LibreOffice (I have it specifically configured to only modify windows from a single application), it clearly causes this issue with LibreOffice.

Disabling (or uninstalling) the `Cinnamon Maximus` extension fixes the reported issue.

Hopefully this will save others a good amount of time.

Comment: please submit an issue https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon-spices-extensions/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+cinnamon-maximus%40fmete